# angularjs after login success redirect home page error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When login success and the page will redirect homepage,I use `$state.go('home')`,but console error [image]
and actually the browser url was changed `http://127.0.0.1:4000/#/home`
I don't know how to fixed.

- userService.js

  ```
  angular.module('app')
  .factory('userService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {


      function retrieveInstance(type, json) {
          var instance = cache[type];

          if (instance) {
              instance.setProperties(json);
              cache[type] = instance;
          }
          return instance;
      }

      return {

          login: function(username, password) {
              var deferred = $q.defer();
              var data = {
                  username: username,
                  password: password
              };

              var noramlUrl = '/login/';

              $http.post(serverUrl + noramlUrl, data)

              .success(function(jsonObj) {
                      if (jsonObj.isSucc) {
                          console.log(jsonObj.msg);
                          deferred.resolve(jsonObj);
                      } else {
                          deferred.reject();
                      }

                  })
                  .error(function() {
                      console.log("login error！");
                      deferred.reject();
                  });

              return deferred.promise;

          },
      };

  }]);
  ```
- app.js

  ```
  angular.module('app', [
      'ngMaterial',
      'ngMessages',
      'material.svgAssetsCache',
      'ui.router',
      'oc.lazyLoad'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',        
      '$ocLazyLoadProvider',
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider)  
      {
          $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
              debug: true,
              catch: true,
              events: true,
              // modules: {
              //  name: '',
              //  files: []
              // }
          });
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
          $stateProvider.state('home', {
                  url: '/home',
                  controller: 'homeCtrl',
                  templateUrl: 'home/template/home.tpl.html',
                  resolve: {
                      load: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                          return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                              'home/controller/home.ctrl.js',
                              'home/css/home.css',
                              'common/css/common.css'
                          ]);
                      }]
                  }
              })
              .state('login', {
                  url: '/login',
                  controller: 'loginCtrl',
                  templateUrl: 'login/template/login.tpl.html',
                  resolve: {
                      load: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                          return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                              'login/controller/login.ctrl.js',
                              'login/service/userService.js',
                              'common/css/common.css',
                              'login/css/login.css'
                          ]);
                      }]
                  }
              });
      }
  ]);

  var serverUrl = 'http://192.168.31.159:8080';

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
  });

                      catch: true,
                      events: true,
                      // modules: {
                      //  name: '',
                      //  files: []
                      // }
                  });
                  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
                  $stateProvider.state('home', {
                          url: '/home',
                          controller: 'homeCtrl',
                          templateUrl: 'home/template/home.tpl.html',
                          resolve: {
                              load: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                                function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                  return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                      'home/controller/home.ctrl.js',
                                      'home/css/home.css',
                                      'common/css/common.css'
                                  ]);
                              }]
                          }
                      })
                      .state('login', {
                          url: '/login',
                          controller: 'loginCtrl',
                          templateUrl: 'login/template/login.tpl.html',
                          resolve: {
                              load: ['$ocLazyLoad', 
                                function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                  return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                      'login/controller/login.ctrl.js',
                                      'login/service/userService.js',
                                      'common/css/common.css',
                                      'login/css/login.css'
                                  ]);
                              }]
                          }
                      });
              }
          ]);

      var serverUrl = 'http://192.168.31.159:8080';

      angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
      });
  ```
- login.ctrl.js

  ```
  angular.module('app', [])

     .controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$http', '$q', 
         'userService', function($scope, $state, $http, $q,  
      userService) {
         $scope.name = "login.ctrl Module";
         console.log($scope.name);


      $scope.login = function() {
          userService.login($scope.username, 
          $scope.password).then(function(json) {
              if (json.isSucc) {
                  console.log(json.isSucc);
                  $state.go('home');
              }
          }, function() {
              console.log("login error ！");
          });
      };

  }]);
  ```

Comment: Could you please share home controller code as well?

Comment: do you have a devtools skin or something?

Comment: @Developer this is home controller ` angular.module('app')

.controller('homeCtrl', [ '$scope','$state', function($scope,$state) {

    console.log('home.ctrl.js');
}]); `  I think that is angular-animate.js method was error, it is worked while I use normal input form ,but I use angular-material

Comment: @martriay it's "DevTools Theme: Zero Dark Matrix" chrome extension